# Clarity Mockups without Sketch on Windows

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm wondering about doing mock-ups using clarity components on Windows without Sketch?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently don't offer anything, but you could try one of the online Sketch file converters to convert the file format to something else that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it was possible to import the Sketch files into Adobe XD, which is available for free on Windows and Mac.